# Illuminate \ Contracts \ Container \ BindingResolutionException

Tags: php, laravel

[Target class [app\Http\controllers\mycontroller] does not exist.
help in this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwaze.png)

Comment: Did you save `web.php`? Where is `mycontroller.php` saved? The name should be `MyController` to comply with PSR-4 standard

Comment: Welcome to SO ... the `App` namespace is `App` not `app` .... you should look into PSR-4 autoloading so you know why you are having this issue